# How to get Selected item value from a selectBox data

Tags: arrays, json, angular, select, drop-down-menu

I have a json file contains objects that have sub-objects like that :

```
[
  {
    "index": 0,
    "name": "Médecine et spécialités médicales",
    "specialties": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Médecine interne"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Maladies infectieuses"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Carcinologie médicale"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "index": 1,
    "name": "Chirurgie et spécialités chirurgicales",
    "specialties": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Chirurgie générale"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Chirurgie carcinologique"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Chirurgie thoracique"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to get the value of selected item every time I change the selected data

here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3av1yr?file=src/assets/json/data.json) that I'm working on, the value of selected item shown as number, how can I get the value as string name field?

Answer (score 0):

According to your stackblitz you passing in value the index not the category name ,
I would do something like this:

**app.html:**

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="selectedCategory">
  <label for="category">Category</label>
  <select
    name="category"
    id="category"
    class="form-control"
    (change)="onCategorySelected($event.target.value)"
  >
    >
    <option
      *ngFor="let category of categories; index as i;"
      [value]="category.name"
    >
      {{ category.name }}
    </option>
  </select>

  <label for="specialty">Specialties</label>
  <select
    [(ngModel)]="selectedSpecialty"
    name="specialty"
    id="specialty"
    class="form-control"
    (change)="onSpecialtySelected($event.target.value)"
  >
    <option
      *ngFor="let specialty of selectedCategory.specialties;"
      [value]="specialty.name"
    >
      {{ specialty.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</ng-template>
```

I had an ng template to avoid console errors and change the value of the first select tag by category.name and remove ngModel (don't know why this doesn't work sorry).

**app.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
interface Speciality{
  name: string
}
interface Category{
  name: string,
  specialities: Speciality[]
}

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  categories: Category[];
  selectedCategory: Category;
  selectedSpecialty: Speciality;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get<Category[]>("assets/json/data.json").subscribe(res => {
      this.categories = res;
      this.selectedCategory = this.categories[0]
    });
  }
  onCategorySelected(categoryName: string) {
    console.log(categoryName);
    this.selectedCategory = this.categories.find(cat => cat.name === categoryName)
  }

  onSpecialtySelected(value: string) {
    console.log(value);
    this.selectedSpecialty.name = value;
  }
}
```

I create interface to type your category and specialities, and in the subscribe method add a line to init your selectedCategory with the first object of your categories array.
here is the link to the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsds79?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a getter. that's you create a function

```
  categories: any=[]; //<--initizalize your variable with a empty array
  get categoryName()
  {
    const cat=this.categories.find((_,index)=>index==this.selectedCategory)
    return cat?cat.name:null
  }
```

Then each time you write in .html

```
{{categoryName}} //you see the category selected
```

And you can forget all yours (change) in select. BTW, remove also the [selected]="i" in your .html. You are using [(ngModel)], so you needn't selected

[your forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjrjdp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)